# Define static QStringList directly

Tags: qt, definition, qstringlist

I want to create and define a static QStringList in an external file.
With gcc ist is possible to do it like this:

```
static QStringList list1 = {item1, item2, item4, ...};
```

But with the visualStudio c++ compiler it is not possible to do it this way. I get the error:

> initializer-list can not be convertedinto QStringList

For me it is important, that I can define the list directly after the declaration.

Because I dont want to define it in the main file.

For example:

main.cpp:

```
#include "stringlist.cpp"    
int main()
{
    QList<QStringList> list;
    list << list1;
}
...
```

stringlist.cpp:

```
#include <QStringList>
static QStringList list1 = {"hi", "hello"};
```

I want to do that because the definition of the QStringList is very long and it is very confusing if such a big definition is somewhere between the other code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to solve the Problem:

You have to type the following snippet into your .pro file.

```
DEFINES += Q_COMPILER_INITIALIZER_LISTS
```

Comment: I get this error message: `error: non-aggregate type 'QStringList' cannot be initialized with an initializer list`, I'm also using QT 5.3.2 and `-no-c++11` so I might not be able to utilize this solution. Or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: It's probably not answer-worthy as it's not a QStringList, but I went with `static QString foo[5] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};`

Comment: @NuclearPeon Im am not sure, but I think, that initializing a list is a thing of c++11. That is the reason, why it does not work. `QString foo[5]` is not a list. It is an array. And arrays could be initialize in c++ versions before c++11. Please correct me if I am wrong.